# Expected sum problem with application of Jensen Inequality

Tags: probability, expected-value, jensen-inequality

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are given random variables with

a) $\mathbb{E}( X + Y ) = \mathbb{E}( X - Y ) = 0$

b) $\text{Var}( X + Y ) = 3$

c) $\text{Var}( X - Y ) = 1$

We have to show $\mathbb{E}| X + Y |<\sqrt{3}$

Now I tried and got $|\mathbb{E}( X + Y) |<\sqrt{3}$ but couldn't establish the relationship using Jensen's inequality. Please help.

Comment: Notice that $|x|=\sqrt{x^2}$

Comment: How did you get $\left|E(X + Y)\right| < \sqrt3$?

Comment: @Henry Var(X + Y ) > 0 then subsequently breaking it.

Comment: @phicar I tried using it but I couldn't set up the inequality thing.

Answer (score 0):

Using the definition of variance

$$Var(X+Y)=\mathbb{E}((X+Y)^2)-\mathbb{E}(X+Y)^2=\mathbb{E}((X+Y)^2),$$

where the last equality follows from a). On the other hand then by b)

$$\mathbb{E}[(X+Y)^2]=\mathbb{E}[|X+Y|^2]=3$$

But because $z^2$ is a convex function, by Jensen's inequality

$$3=\mathbb{E}[|X+Y|^2]>\mathbb{E}[|X+Y|]^2$$

Therefore taking square roots and given the positivity of $\mathbb{E}[|X+Y|]$, we obtain

$$\mathbb{E}[|X+Y|]<\sqrt{3}.$$

Comment: Thank you very much. I was in the right path actually but just shuffled things.