# Expectation calculation of a function for bivariate normal distribution

Tags: probability, expected-value

I am struggling with parts b and c of the question below, covariance value is 1/2, for the remaining parts, any help would be much appreciated
[image: question]

Comment: Hint for (b): $\mathbb{E}|X| \leq (\mathbb{E}|X|^2)^{1/2}$

Comment: Recently asked: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3756880/321264.

Answer (score 1):

a) ok

b) the condition $\mathbb{E}(X+Y)=0$ implies also $V(X+Y)=\mathbb{E}(X+Y)^2$

to finish the proof it is enough observe that

$\mathbb{E}|X+Y|=\mathbb{E}\sqrt{(X+Y)^2}$

and using [Jensen's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality) you immediately get:

$$\mathbb{E}[\sqrt{(X+Y)^2}] \leq \sqrt{\mathbb{E}(X+Y)^2}$$

c) it is very easy,

$(X+Y)\sim N(0;3)$ thus $f_{|X+Y|}(t)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{6\pi}}e^{-\frac{t^2}{6}}$; $t\geq 0$

Now,

$$\mathbb{E}|X+Y|^3=\int_0^{+\infty}t^3\frac{2}{\sqrt{6\pi}}e^{-\frac{t^2}{6}}dt$$

Letting $\frac{t^2}{6}=u$ the integral becomes

$$6\sqrt{\frac{6}{\pi}}\int_o^{+\infty} ue^{-u}du=6\sqrt{\frac{6}{\pi}}$$

Anyway when posting a question show your efforts (using [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) an not pictures)